# Why does my movement system randomly break?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Here is the full code:

```
import random
import numpy as np

world = {}

class Player():
  def __init__(self, health, maxHealth, baseDmg, dmg, name, weapons, items, isAlive, previousRoom, roomName):
    self.health = health
    self.maxHealth = maxHealth
    self.baseDmg = baseDmg
    self.dmg = dmg
    self.name = name
    self.weapons = weapons
    self.items = items
    self.isAlive = isAlive
    self.previousRoom = previousRoom
    self.room = world[roomName]

  def Move(self, direction):
    if direction not in self.room.exits:
      print("Cannot Move In That Direction!")
      return
    newRoomName = self.room.exits[direction]
    self.previousRoom = world[self.room.name]
    print("Moving to", newRoomName)
    self.room = world[newRoomName]

  def MoveBack(self):
    self.room = world[self.previousRoom.name]
    print("Moving to", self.room.name)

class Enemy():
  def __init__(self, health, dmg, hasLoot, lootItem, isAlive):
    self.health = health
    self.dmg = dmg
    self.hasLoot = hasLoot
    self.lootItem = lootItem
    self.isAlive = isAlive

class Weapon():
  def __init__(self, name, dmg, description):
    self.name = name
    self.dmg = dmg
    self.description = description

class Item():
  def __init__(self, name, amt, description):
    self.name = name
    self.amt = amt
    self.description = description

class Room():
  def __init__(self, name, description, exits, hasWeapon, weapon, hasItem, item, hasEnemy, enemy, isFirstVisit, coords):
    self.name = name
    self.description = description
    self.exits = exits
    self.hasWeapon = hasWeapon
    self.weapon = weapon
    self.hasItem = hasItem
    self.item = item
    self.hasEnemy = hasEnemy
    self.enemy = enemy
    self.isFirstVisit = isFirstVisit
    self.coords = coords

#######################Dungeon Generation###################
rooms = np.zeros((11, 11))
maxRooms = 7
possibleNextRoom = []

def startLevel():
  for r in range(len(rooms[0])):
    for c in range(len(rooms[1])):
      rooms[r][c] = 0

  possibleNextRoom.clear()

  halfHeight = int(len(rooms[1]) / 2)
  halfWidth = int(len(rooms[0]) / 2)
  rooms[halfWidth][halfHeight] = 1

def resetLevel():
  for r in range(len(rooms[0])):
    for c in range(len(rooms[1])):
      rooms[r][c] = 0
  
  possibleNextRoom.clear()

def countRooms():

  roomCount = 0

  for r in range(len(rooms)):
    for c in range(len(rooms)):
      if rooms[r][c] == 1:
        roomCount += 1

  return roomCount

def findPossibleRooms():

  for r in range(len(rooms) - 1):
    for c in range(len(rooms) - 1):
      if rooms[r][c] == 1:
        if rooms[r][c+1] != 1:
          possibleNextRoom.append((r, c+1))
        if rooms[r][c-1] != 1:
          possibleNextRoom.append((r, c-1))
        if rooms[r-1][c] != 1:
          possibleNextRoom.append((r-1, c))
        if rooms[r+1][c] != 1:
          possibleNextRoom.append((r+1, c))

def addRoom():
  x = random.randrange(0, len(possibleNextRoom))

  rooms[possibleNextRoom[x][0]][possibleNextRoom[x][1]] = 1
  possibleNextRoom.pop(x)

def generateLevel():

  global x, possibleNextRoom

  startLevel()

  while countRooms() < maxRooms:
    countRooms()
    findPossibleRooms()
    addRoom()

def makeRoomsForLevel():

  counter = 1

  for r in range(len(rooms)):
    for c in range(len(rooms)):
      if rooms[c][r] == 1:
        world[f"room{counter}"] = Room(
          f"room{counter}",
          "",
          {},
          False,
          None,
          False,
          None,
          False,
          None,
          True,
          (r, c)
        )
        counter += 1

def findRoom(x, y):
  for i in range(len(world)):
      if world[f"room{i+1}"].coords == (x, y):
        return f"room{i+1}"
  return None

def findExits():
  for i in range(len(world)):
      x, y = world[f"room{i+1}"].coords
      exits = dict()
      
      #east
      if rooms[x, y+1] == 1:
          exits["E"] = findRoom(x, y+1)
      
      #south
      if rooms[x+1, y] == 1:
          exits["S"] = findRoom(x+1, y)
      
      #west
      if rooms[x, y-1] == 1:
          exits["W"] = findRoom(x, y-1)
      
      #north
      if rooms[x-1, y] == 1:
          exits["N"] = findRoom(x-1, y)
          
      world[f"room{i+1}"].exits = exits

############################################################

generateLevel()
makeRoomsForLevel()
findExits()

WoodenSword = Weapon("Wooden Sword", 5, "A wooden sword. Looks like a kid's toy.")
IronDagger = Weapon("Iron Dagger", 8, "Small, sharp, and pointy. Good for fighting monsters!")

HealthPot = Item("Health Potion", 1, "A Potion of Instant Health. Restores 10 Health.")

goblin1 = Enemy(25, 2, True, [HealthPot, IronDagger], True)

player = Player(10, 10, 5, 5, "", [], [], True, "room1", "room1")

def ShowInv():
  print("*******************************")
  print("Name:", player.name)
  print("Health:", player.health)
  print("Weapons:")
  for i in player.weapons:
    print(" ===============================")
    print(" Weapon:", i.name)
    print(" Description:", i.description)
    print(" Damage:", i.dmg)
    print(" ===============================")
  print("Items:")
  for i in player.items:
    print(" ===============================")
    print(" Item:", i.name)
    print(" Amount:", i.amt)
    print(" Description:", i.description)
    print(" ===============================")
  print("*******************************")

def testItems(item):
  exists = item in player.items
  return exists

def fight(enemy):
  print("Your Health:", player.health)
  print("Enemy Health:", enemy.health)

  ans = input("What would you like to do?\n>>")
  if ans == "attack":
    chance = random.randrange(1, 20)
    if chance >= 10:
      enemy.health -= player.dmg
    else:
      print("You did not roll high enough...\nYour turn has been passed...")

  if ans == "heal":
    chance = random.randrange(1, 20)
    if testItems(HealthPot):
      if chance >= 10:
        x = 0
        for item in player.items:
          if item == HealthPot:
            player.health += 10
            if player.health > player.maxHealth:
              player.health = player.maxHealth
            item.amt -= 1
            if item.amt <= 0:
              player.items.pop(x)
              break
          x += 1
      else:
        print("You did not roll high enough...\nYour turn has been passed...")

  if ans == "run":
    chance = random.randrange(1, 20)
    if chance >= 10:
      player.MoveBack()
    else:
      print("You did not roll high enough...\nYour turn has been passed...")

  if enemy.health > 0 and player.health > 0:
    chance  = random.randrange(1, 20)
    if chance >= 10:
      player.health -= enemy.dmg
  else:
    if enemy.health <= 0:
      enemy.isAvile = False;

def testRoom():
  if player.room.hasWeapon:
    if player.room.isFirstVisit:
      player.weapons.append(player.room.weapon)
  
  if player.room.hasItem:
    if player.room.isFirstVisit:
      player.items.append(player.room.item)

  if player.room.hasEnemy:
    if player.room.isFirstVisit:
      while player.room.enemy.health > 0:
        fight(player.room.enemy)

  player.room.isFirstVisit = False


while True:
  command = input(">>")

  if command in {"N", "S", "E", "W"}:
    player.Move(command)
    testRoom()

  elif command == "look":
    print(player.room.description)
    print("Exits:", *','.join(list(player.room.exits.keys())))

  elif command == "inv":
    ShowInv()

  elif command == "heal":
    if testItems(HealthPot):
      player.health += 10
      if player.health > player.maxHealth:
        player.health = player.maxHealth
    else:
      print("You don't have any", HealthPot.name, "\bs")

  else:
    print("Invalid Command")
```

And here is the problem:

Everything seems to work fine, until a couple moves in when it breaks and gives me a "KeyError: None" for the room I just walked in. I have no idea what could be causing this, and I am fairly new, so please simplify the explanations for me. I think it has something to do with the findExits() function and findRoom() function, but idk.

Here is the TraceBackError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 287, in <module>
    player.Move(command)
  File "main.py", line 26, in Move
    self.room = world[newRoomName]
KeyError: None
```

I've tried fiddling with the function, but nothing i've tried worked. Here is the repl.it link:
https://replit.com/@samsonsbrother0/Dungeon-Crawler#main.py

Comment: KeyErrors (as with other Exceptions) usually come with a traceback that identify the specific line number. Could you supply the traceback?

Comment: Please provide a [**minimal**, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You should at least give us the traceback error and the inputs you use to replicate it. Ideally though you locate in which function it occurs (the traceback tells you this) and isolate that by hardcoding its state and input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is accessing a key before it exists, thus the error. to fix it, you need to assign the newroomname to the world dict as you move, like so:

```
print("Moving to", newRoomName)
world[newRoomName] = newRoomName
self.room = world[newRoomName]
```

Comment: also, you have an incorrect semicolon on this line enemy.isAvile = False;